# How to bypass unique ID and retrieve multiple auto generated child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve multiple child with an auto generated child(Estab_url child). Here is my Code. All i can retrieve is one child and its random

[image: Our Database Firebase]

```
final DatabaseReference establishments = database.getReference("establishments");


  establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_url").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                 //   String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    String sd = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Name.setText(sd);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to read the URL value for each child:

```
establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_url").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String url = dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
        Name.setText(url);
    }
```

If that is not what you're looking for, please update your question to rephrase the problem.

**Update**

If you'd like to catch all URLs in a list, you'd set up the list outside of the listener and then add each URL to it as it comes in:

```
List<String> urls = new LinkedList<String>();
establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_url").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String url = dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
        urls.add(url);
        // TODO: do something with the up-to-date list of URLs
    }
```

But note that you still cannot use the list *outside* of the listener. Any code that needs the up-to-date content of the list, will need to be called/triggered from within (in this case) `onChildAdded`.

Comment: How can i get the values of child url?

Comment: That is precisely what my code does: it gets the value of the `url` property. Did you try it? What does it do for you?

Comment: that is exactly what i meant. but my problem is that i can only get one value of the url, i also would like to get the first value of the url in the first child.

Comment: Is it even possible to retrieve 2 url's in this structure?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your `onChildAdded` will already be called for both child nodes. So you're getting both URLs. But you then set them to the same `Name.setText()`, meaning that the second URL replaces the value of the first URL. To see this, either log the values (`System.out.println(url)`) or append the URL to name (`Name.setText(Name.getText() + "-" + url);`).

Comment: can you help me on how to store the two url in a variable ? or in an array ?

Comment: I added a snippet for that.

Comment: Thank you, we want to use the value of the url and use it in Picasso. The value of the url is actually a link from Firebase Storage which I would like to display in an imageView. Every url should have different imageView. Can you help me with that? Please