# Picasso Dynamic Image Url passing date

Tags: android, firebase, picasso, firebase-storage

I want to put the value of the url into the [.load(url)] of picasso i cant pass it dont know why. But i can load the value of url in a Textview. Please help i know its very simple. Please I need HELP (Newbie)

```
    package com.maasin.map.anew.model;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.maasin.map.anew.R;
import com.maasin.map.anew.model.model.Local;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.attr.defaultValue;
import static android.R.attr.drawable;
import static android.R.attr.name;
import static android.R.attr.value;
import static android.R.attr.valueFrom;

/**
 * Created by Carl Christian on 11/02/2017.
 */

public class establishment extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback  {

    TextView Name;
   // TextView Name2;
    TextView add;
    TextView Categ;
    TextView oStart;
    TextView oEnd;
    Toolbar tool;
  String s;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;

    double latt = 124.838767;
    double longg = 10.134265;

    double longitude = 124.831786 ;
    double latitude = 10.130952;
  //String url;
 //   List<String> urls = new LinkedList<String>();


    Context ctx = this;


    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


        final DatabaseReference establishments = database.getReference("establishments");


        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        s = getIntent().getStringExtra("PRIMEKEY");
        String s2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("PRIMEKEY2");
        latitude= getIntent().getDoubleExtra("location", defaultValue);
        longitude= getIntent().getDoubleExtra("location1", defaultValue);
     //   Toast.makeText(this,Double.toString(l), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        // Toast.makeText(establishment.this, s2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
          //      .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        //mamapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        //map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          //      .position(new LatLng(124.838767, 10.134265))
            //    .title("Hello world"));

      //  StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://newtest-e7dff.appspot.com/");

        //StorageReference imagesRef = storageRef.child(s2);







//from main activity , title action bar
        Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        //Name.setText(s2);

        //  Name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name2);

        add = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.add);
        // Name2.setText(s2);
        oStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oStart);

        oEnd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oEnd);

        Categ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Categ);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);





        //FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       // DatabaseReference mref = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_url").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           //  String url = dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
               // url = dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
               // Name.setText(Html.fromHtml("&ldquo;" + url + "&rdquo;" ));
               // String gg = (Html.fromHtml("&ldquo;" + url + "&rdquo;" ));
                //urls.add(url);
             //   Name.setText(url);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                Picasso.with(ctx)
                        .load(dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class))
                        .resize(200,100)
                        .into(imageView);

            }

            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore onCancelled
            }
        });

       // Name.setText(urls);



     //   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
     //   Name.setText(url);
  //  Picasso.with(this)
        //     .load(url)
            //   .resize(200,100)
           //     .into(imageView);







        // String x =  establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_name").toString();
        // Name2.setText(x);
        // final DatabaseReference establishments = database.getReference("establishments");



        establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                //Name.setText(value);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });




      //  establishments.child(s2).child("latitude").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        //    @Override
          //  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //    String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
              //  double amount = Double.parseDouble(value);
                //latitude= amount;
              //  Toast.makeText(this,value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // }

//            @Override
  //          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    //        }
      //  });



//        establishments.child(s2).child("longitude").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  //          @Override
    //        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      //          String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        //        double amount = Double.parseDouble(value);
          //      longitude= amount;

            //}

//            @Override
  //          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

//            }
  //      });










        establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_add").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                add.setText(value);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });





        establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_category").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                Categ.setText(value);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_Officestart").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                oStart.setText(value);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_Officeout").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                oEnd.setText(value);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;




        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        float zoomLevel = 16;
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(s));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, zoomLevel));
    }

}
```

Comment: Everyday question... Code inside `onChildXXX()` is executed async. That means, that code below it will be executed before you got url

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. This means that by the time you set the image with Picasso, the `url` hasn't been set yet.

You can most easily see this by placing a few log statements in your code:

```
System.out.println("Before attaching listener");
establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_url").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        System.out.println("In onChildAdded");
    }

    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore onCancelled
    }
});
System.out.println("After attaching listener");
```

When you run this code, it will print:

> Before attaching listener
>
> After attaching listener
>
> In onChildAdded

That is probably not the order you expected. But it completely explains why your code fails to load the image: the URL isn't available yet.

The solution is to reframe the problem. Instead of thinking "first I'll read the URL, then I'll set it in an image", reframe it as "I'll start reading the URL, when it's available I'll set it in an image".

The latter way of thinking means that you move the code that needs the URL into `onChildAdded` (in this case). So you end up with:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Context ctx = this;

establishments.child(s2).child("Estab_url").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String url = dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
        Picasso.with(ctx)
            .load(url)
            .resize(200,100)
            .into(imageView);
    }

    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore onCancelled
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont know whats wrong but when i tried the code above the app crashes. No error when building it. I tried it with .load(url) and this .load("&ldquo;" + url + "&rdquo;" ) to add "" in the url

Comment: There's no need to include the quote characters in the child name. It's just `url` in the database. If you're experiencing a crash you need to edit your question to include your data structure in plain text, the new code, a stack trace, and indicate which line of the code throws the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your help Frank we can now retrieve one image. Our problem now is to retrieve multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute Picasso load in the onChildAdded callback. Since onChildAdded is asynchronous your load must be done after the callback.

```
  @Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    String url = dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
    Log.v("Url content", "value:" + url); // Added this log
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .resize(200,100)
            .into(imageView);
}
```

Comment: Now the app doesnt crash anymore but it wont show the image from the URL i dont know what to do

Comment: Please share your code with a repository or something else

Comment: Nicola , here is my establishment.class . Below my question . Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: I can't build your code to test it, add some log to onChildAdded method to watch what's in url variable

Comment: Hi Mr. Gallazzi , can you help me with this problem ?? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375899/how-to-bypass-unique-id-and-retrieve-multiple-auto-generated-child/42376447?noredirect=1#comment71984049_42376447)

Comment: Thank you for your help Nicola we can now retrieve one image. Our problem now is to retrieve multiple images.